# Finding the index of HTML element Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I am trying to write the step definition, using Capybara, for a Cucumber scenario that is meant to confirm that checkboxes on the home page appear before the options.

Mechanically, I am trying to find the index of a specific html checkbox using its HTML ID and compare it with the index of a specific text on the home page. However, I have spent hours on this issue and have not been able to implement the step definition.

Would I for example be able to somehow convert the page into text and just search for words?

For this web application I am using Ruby on Rails. 

Let: checkbox id = environment_Cool 

Let: text on the page = Cool

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Please add an example of the html

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a checkbox like this:

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  <span>
  <input type="checkbox" name="coolness" value="Cool" id="environment_Cool"  checked> Cool</span>
  <br>
  <span>
  <input type="checkbox" name="coolness" value="Cool"> Not So Cool</span><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

> Mechanically, I am trying to find the index of a specific html
>   checkbox using its HTML ID

```
page.find('[@id=environment_Cool ]')
```

> and compare it with the index of a specific text on the home page.
>   Then it should return the text at the parent of the checklist, which is "Cool".

```
puts page.find('[@id=environment_Cool ]').find(:xpath,".//..").text
```

Comment: What does page.find('[@id=environment_Cool ]') return? Does it return the index? Also would I be able to use page.find('Cool') to find the index of a 'Cool' text on the home page?

Comment: Would you please elaborate on page.find('[@id=environment_Cool ]').find(:xpath,".//..").text   I don't understand what it's trying to find.